# Ionic installation on macOs

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install ionic and every time I try to install it says:

> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead

and I can't even check `ionic -v` to check version as it is not installed.
I can check npm version as it is installed correctly.

```
➜  ~ node -v
v8.7.0

➜  ~ npm -v
5.4.2

➜  ~ npm install -g cordova ionic
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/Users/bilaltariq/.npm-packages/bin/cordova -> /Users/bilaltariq/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/Users/bilaltariq/.npm-packages/bin/ionic -> /Users/bilaltariq/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
+ cordova@7.1.0
+ ionic@3.13.2
updated 2 packages in 27.258s
```

Comment: Thats just a deprecation warning for node-uuid. Everything is fine, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: but i cant run ionic -v and check the version and cant even created a new app with ionic. every time i run ionic -v it says command not found

Comment: @David is it because of this path issue **/Users/bilaltariq/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic**

Comment: Try installing it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The fix is to install ionic CLI globally:

As the developer user execute the following from your ionic project root directory:

```
npm uninstall ionic
```

then as user "root" execute the following:

```
npm i -g ionic@latest
```

after that, you should be able to use the new ionic CLI version 4.12.0